# Enabling Azure blob storage for Kubernetes using CSI

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cloud, devops, azure-aks

Currently, I am trying to dynamically provision the Azure blob storage for Kubernetes using Container Storage Interface plugin. The Azure documentation is quite confusing. The [github](https://%20https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver/blob/master/deploy/example/e2e_usage.md) says, Just create storage class and continue creating stateful set. The integration is complete.

While the official [Azure Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-blob-csi?tabs=Blobfuse) says, Create PVC and a pod followed by stateful set. This still seems like an incomplete doc, which is pretty unclear for me. Any leads on the same will be much appreciated.

How this works exactly ? My understanding is, create a PVC and statefulset after creating a storage class, and it should be working. If Anyone has implemented this in your project, please shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an understanding about these phenomena. We can create Persistence Volume Claim by two ways. The first way is to create a separate resource file where kind is a Persistent Volume Claim, and the other way is to rely on Statefulset. It's up to the user to decide whether they want to use a Statefulset or rely on a PVC file.

To dynamically provision the Azure Blob Storage, Install CSI Driver in the target environment and create a storage class. Create a Persistence Volume Claim (PVC)  resource and use the target storage class name in it. Now, whenever the PVC resource is deployed, it dynamically fetches the required volume from the storage class automatically. Quite straightforward and simple.